# Was there a rep recalculation?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I just lost about 226 reputation within past 2 hours or so...what is going here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Someone probably thought that they were doing you a favour by up-voting a lot of your answers in quick succession. This would have triggered the vote fraud mechanism which would have removed the votes and in turn triggered a reputation recalculation. This will result in a loss of points - probably greater than the up-votes you received due to deleted questions.

The other, less charitable, alternative is that you had a sock-puppet account which was up-voting your main account. This was detected, the sock-puppet account deleted and with it its votes - which again would trigger a reputation recalculation. **However, I haven't seen any evidence of this so I've only included it here for completeness sake.**